# How to disable F10/F11 unless I'm debugging in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

So I have this weird problem where I press keys subconsciously sometimes. <kbd>F10</kbd> (step over) and <kbd>F11</kbd> (step into) are two that I keep pressing... or if I meant to hit <kbd>F12</kbd>, sometimes I hit <kbd>F11</kbd> accidently...

Anyway, this is a major annoyance since it starts a build, which takes a while, I immediately start spamming <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>BREAK</kbd> to break the build, but it only rarely works; it seems that it just freezes or maybe there is only a short window of time where it does work? Then if the build succeeds, my configuration is set up to do a deploy as well, and often, VS just locks and I have to end the process with Task Manager and restart VS.

So just wondering if there is any possibility to only allow <kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>F11</kbd> to work when pressed if I am debugging, where I actually need it (I use attach to process so <kbd>F5</kbd>/<kbd>F10</kbd>/<kbd>F11</kbd> are useless shortcuts when *not* debugging)?

Thanks.

Comment: Put on a shock collar for a dog and wire it into the F10 and F11 keys.  Within no time you will stop pressing buttons by accident.

Comment: @MatthewWhited That made me laugh, I had to upvote it! :)

Comment: It would be pretty easy to do with an arduino.  You could even use bluetooth to make it wireless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign <kbd>F10</kbd> to the following C# command for [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/):

```
    if (DTE.Mode == vsIDEMode.vsIDEModeDebug)
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("Debug.StepOver");
```

It will call StepOver only when you are in the Debug mode. For <kbd>F11</kbd> use Debug.StepInto.

Comment: Will this work if I have a custom configuration set (other than Debug)?

Comment: Yes, I think so. It checks the debug mode, not the configuration name.

Comment: Awesome, that worked! Debug.Start seems to be the command name for F5.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - kept randomly hitting F11 instead of F12.  I ended up re-assigning F10 and F11 to something innocuous (like Find Next / Previous) and then re-assigned StepOver / StepInto to Ctrl-' and ctrl-; respectively (these are the same shortcut keys used by the Chrome debugger).

Perhaps a bit extreme, but it works for me.  I now have a new problem though where I occasionally invoke Find Next when debugging :)  On balance the new problem is less annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to drdan, I shifted F10 (stepover), and f11 (stepinto / build & enter debug), over to the left by one F key.

F9 (add a breakoint on current line) is pretty useless if you own a mouse. Unless you prefer to use the arrow keys + F8 add a breakpoint, in which case, well, I can't help you :)

So I removed F9 from add breakpoint, and now F11 is bound to nothing.
Remember there are also related modifier keys associated to F11 and F10.

Wish M$ UX AI LLM Cortana AlwaysOnline 365 720 Cowabunga ™ whatever, had the decency to also let you search the key bindings menus by key, (e.g. F9), as well as by command (e.g. addbreakpoint)..